# Is there a dark mode for Catboost fitting plot?

Tags: python, plot, darkmode, catboost

It seems there is no darkmode easily accessible for catboost fitting plot.
The documentation does not seem to contain anything on the subject.

I am running my Jupyter Notebook into VS code and I am using these lines to get dark modes with seaborn and matplotlib:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set(style="darkgrid", context="talk")
plt.style.use("dark_background")
plt.rcParams.update({"grid.linewidth":0.5, "grid.alpha":0.5})
```

I have look briefly at the source code of their widget but couldn't find the attribute that defines the background color.

```py
from catboost import CatBoostRegressor, Pool

train_dataset = Pool(X_train,y_train)
test_dataset  = Pool(X_test,y_test)

model = CatBoostRegressor()
model.fit(
    X=train_dataset,
    eval_set=test_dataset,
    plot=True
)
```

What can I do to have darkplots here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround is to add the following code to a Jupyter cell:

```
%%html
<style>
.catboost {
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
}

.catboost .main-svg {
    filter: invert(1);
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no dark mode specifically for `catboost`. Giving a look at their [Docs](https://catboost.ai/en/docs/concepts/python-reference_catboost_fit) it is evident that currently they have no support for dark modes.

Comment: I agree with that, isn't there a work around ? There must be some attributes you can change in the widget code or that you can override directly in the notebook before displaying the widget.